# How to calculate log-rank test statistic

Tags: survival, nonparametric, logrank-test

Depending on which statistics text you read you will get 2 different formulations of the log-rank test statistic. In some texts you will see it specified as:

$$
\frac{(O-E)^2}{E}
$$
[Example 1](https://www.bmj.com/content/328/7447/1073)

Whilst in others you will see it as
$$
\frac{(O-E)^2}{V}
$$

[Example 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrank_test)
[Example 2](https://web.stanford.edu/~lutian/coursepdf/unitweek3.pdf)

My questions are:

- Do these variants have specific names?
- Do they have any differences in properties?
- When should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is related to the chi-squared test. The second one is the log-rank test that I am aware of. The problem with running a chi-squared test in survival statistics is that the tests at various time points are not independent (i.e. to be considered for a later time point someone must survive an earlier time point), so I would not recommend using it. In general with survival analysis use the second variant (truly I think it is the primary methodology).

It can be shown that the second variant approaches a z-distribution (N(0,1)) and a chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom when squaring the statistic as shown [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~lutian/coursepdf/unitweek3.pdf).

Comment: Is there any comparative study you are aware of which demonstrates that second one is better, e.g, in terms of power and type I error?